# Java Time/Date format

Tags: java, date, time, format

Simple question it's night here and I don't want to wait till morning

At 6AM:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
```

Will sdf be 06, or just 6

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It will be 06, not 6.

have a look at this if you need more help on the date/time format

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this 
SimpleDateFormat sdf; 
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss"); 
and use 06 instead of 6